# How to clusterize points lying on the sphere

Tags: clustering

---

I want to cluster protein conformations by dihedrals angles.
My point is an n-dimensional vector, where is n - number of dihedral angles.
I think I can't use Euclidean distance for distance metric because of the distance between +179 degrees and -179 degrees is 2 degree, not 358.

Can you suggest some clustering algorithms and distance metrics for such tasks?
Maybe some algorithms from geo points clusterization.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the setup, but wouldn't these be points on a torus rather than a sphere?  Maybe read through https://www.reddit.com/r/MLQuestions/comments/a44e1k/clustering_algorithm_for_a_torus/

Answer (score 2):

You have circular variables.
One way to deal with them is to create two variables for each:
sin(alpha_1), cos(alpha_1), sin(alpha_2), cos(alpha_2), ...
Then you can use regular clustering algorithms.

There exists custom algorithms for circular data.
Examples: [Unsupervised clustering of multivariate circular data](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00674196v2/document)